# how long a ftp/sftp session can be opened?

Tags: ftp, sftp

I wonder how long an ftp or sftp session can remain open? The reason I'm asking is I have some legacy code which opens an ftp session using `WinSCPnet.dll` then calls db to create a file and dump it in a location to do sftp.

This is about trying to open a session:

> [SessionOptions Class](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_sessionoptions#properties)
>
> TimeSpan Timeout  Server response timeout. Defaults to 15 seconds.

But how long does it stay open?

Comment: How many months do you need it to stay open?

Comment: @MichaelHampton do u know how long? 1 hr? 1 day? 1 month?...

Comment: On a clean network connection with no interference and defaults all around, an ssh session will stay open indefinitely.

Answer (score 3):

This may depend on several factors:

- timeout limit on the SSH host
- timeout limit on an intermediate firewall or NAT router (aging)
- timeout limit on your client

The earliest timeout defines how long the session can be open.